# Why is this number being rounded down?

Tags: php, math, numbers

I have two prices that are the following:

1199,95
800

I want both to end up like:

```
800,00
1199,95
```

So I did the following:

```
echo number_format($cartproduct1['price'],2,",",".");
```

But this gives me:

```
800,00
1.199,00
```

Why is my number being rounded down?

For example if I got a price of 0,10 it shows as 0,00 on my page.

I am using dutch numerics, so a comma for cents and a dot for larger numbers.

0,10 or 1.000.000,00

Comment: you cannot round numbers with an `,` as decimal-seperator

Comment: You should store the numbers with a dot not a comma. After that you should be able to use number format. Also keep in mind that if you just want the first section to be in a number format, you can use explode and number format

Comment: If you mean that you don't have regular float variables but strings with localised numbers, well, doing maths with text is hard—that's why computer languages have numeric types available.

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the `,` with `.`

```
$a = '800,00';
$b = '1199,95'; 

$a = str_repace (',', '.' $a);
$b = str_repace (',', '.' $b);

echo number_format ($a, 2, '', '.');
echo number_format ($b, 2, '', '.');
```